# Cloud Firestore: Query does not find a document but document exists

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a game, and I am trying to create a system of rooms. I am trying to query for rooms that are not filled, and have the user join the first one. The problem is that I am querying for a document where "filled" == false. I have one in my database, but it is not finding it.

```
let query = roomsRef.where("filled","==","false").get().then(function(snap){
    console.log(snap.size);
    if(snap.docs[0].data()){
        roomId = snap.docs[0].id;
        roomsRef.doc(roomId).update({
            filled: true,
            user2: username
        });
        return;
    }
});
```

The code above is returning "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is because the returned value is not an array
is an object with a method to iterate the documents from your db

```
let query = roomsRef.where("filled", "==", false).get().then(function(snap){
  snap.forEach(doc){
    roomId = doc.id;
    roomsRef.doc(roomId).update({
        filled: true,
        user2: username
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I tested your code, and the problem was that I was checking for false as a string, not a boolean.